# Zookeeper for assigning shard indexes

Tags: java, sharding, apache-zookeeper

I've seen some posts online about using Zookeeper to assign shard numbers to servers as they come online (assuming you are sharding data across a cluster) - but for the life of me cannot find a Java code example of how to do this.  Anyone have this working already?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of details in sharding data across a cluster, such as replication and recovery from failure.  I am assuming by sharding that you mean that you have *N* nodes, and each node should handle *1/N* th of the requests, and that clients can discover which servers are up.

You first create a persistent node `/service`.  Each server creates an [ephemeral](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperOver.html#Nodes+and+ephemeral+nodes) child of `/service` when it starts, something like `/service/hostname:port`.  Clients maintain a [watch](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches) on `/service` and get notified when children are added and removed (clients must renew their watch after every notification).  This way the client knows what servers are up serving requests, and can distribute requests as appropriate (round robin, random).  When a server goes down, it's ephemeral node will disappear, and clients can stop sending it requests.

If you are looking for a zookeeper library, [curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki) is probably the best one.  Clients would use a [Path-Cache](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Path-Cache), while the server simply creates an ephemeral node.